# tag_bind method of Canvas in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

I want to bind multiple handlers to the event  on images drawn on canvas using create_image method.
But only one handler is working..The first one.

```
systemcanvas.tag_bind(image_id,'<ButtonRelease-1>',fun1)
systemcanvas.tag_bind(image_id, "<ButtonRelease-1>", fun2)
```

How to make both the functions bound to the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After binding an event to a widget or canvas item the command is bound till you unbind or overwrite it. You overwrite it simply by bounding a new command to that item or widget, to avoid that you can add the optional argument `add='+'`.

```
import tkinter as tk

def test1(event):
    print('test 1 is running')
def test2(event):
    print('test 2 is running')

root = tk.Tk()
cnvs = tk.Canvas(root)
itm  = cnvs.create_text(0,0, anchor='nw',text='default')
cnvs.tag_bind(itm,'<Button-1>', test1)
cnvs.tag_bind(itm,'<Button-1>', test2,add='+')
cnvs.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

> If script is prefixed with a “+”, then it is appended to any existing
> binding for sequence; otherwise script replaces any existing binding.
> If script is an empty string then the current binding for sequence is
> destroyed, leaving sequence unbound. In all of the cases where a
> script argument is provided, bind returns an empty string.

[Source](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/bind.htm#M4)

Comment: I know that `add="+"` works but according to `tkinter`'s source code *"An additional boolean parameter ADD specifies whether FUNC will be called additionally to the other bound function or whether it will replace the previous function."* Doesn't that mean that `add` should be `True` instead of `"+"`?

Comment: That is from `tcl`'s docs. `_tkinter` manages the script names/calling so we should look at `tkinter`'s docs

Comment: @TheLizzard do what you like to do.